# why does a MYSQL syntax error say the error is on a certain line, when that line is empty?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I got this error from my PHP page:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''' at line 9
```

In my file, I don't even have anything on line 9, and the html file is only 1 line long.

Here are lines 7 through 14 in my file:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM 3zonesField WHERE ID = '0' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

print_r($result);
$Field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

$query = "SELECT * FROM 3zonesHouse WHERE ID = '0' LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: It's talking about a specific query that has 9 (or more lines); not line 9 in your PHP file: MySQL isn't aware of the contents of your PHP file at all

Comment: `ThreezonesField` instead of `3zonesField` maybe ? I think table name shouldn't start with a number.

Comment: `WHERE ID = '0'` hm... if your `ID` field is set to AUTO_INCREMENT, then that value will/should start at `1` - try removing the quotes around it and use `WHERE ID=0` or `WHERE ID=1` or `WHERE ID=?` really hard to say, and the problem may even lie elsewhere (in un-posted code)

Comment: This has nothing to do with your question but for your own good, I'd suggest learning to program with mysqli, or a more suggested option, PDO.

Comment: The field is not set to auto-increment, and i have not had a problem in the past with my table names starting with numbers.

Comment: Post your full code then. I see nothing wrong with what's posted. @filler003 something else is causing this.

Comment: And thanks Mark Baker, I didn't know it wasn't talking about the php file.  Is there a way I can find out which query it is talking about other than using echo statements in between them to see where it stops?

Comment: If you're using an include for your DB connection or other, than those lines inside those/that file(s) will count as lines. So, what you posted is (next to) irrelevant, at least IMO.

Comment: I found the problem, the quotes in one of my queries didn't match up.   I was just thrown off because I didn't realize the error was talking about line 9 in the query and not in the php file.